# Index incremental function bind to a button in Angular doesn't increment the index and do not iterate through array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, loops, ngfor

Index incremental function bind to a button in Angular doesn't increment the index and do not iterate through array on the button click. No matter how many times I keep clicking the button, I see the same first `[0]` question from array. Why is so?

***component.html***

```
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{questions}}</h5>
    <input *ngFor="let answer of answers"
    type="radio" name="ans" [value]="answer"> {{answer}}<br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="nextQuestion()">Go somewhere</button>
  </div>
```

***component.ts***

```
export class QuostionnaireComponent implements OnInit {
  questions:any;
  answers:any;
  correstAnswers:any;
  incremental:Observable = 0;
  constructor(private questionnaire: QuestionnaireService) {
        this.questions = this.questionnaire.theQuestion[this.incremental];
        this.answers = this.questionnaire.theChoices[this.incremental];
   }
   nextQuestion():void {
     this.incremental++;
   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

How can I iterate through array of questions and answers on button click correctly?

Also in my radio buttons, values work fine and I get all three answer options bind to `[value]` but there are no words next to a radio button, it's like my `> {{answer}}<br>` gets ignored. No errors, though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not going in details of your code, but constructor initializes once so you always stay on the same value which happens to be `[0]` in your case. You may want to move your constructor code to `ngOnInit` and then probably re-assign questions/answers in `ngOnChanges`

Comment: @Rikin Thanks, I didn't know that. But that still doesn't help. In docs for `ngOnChanges` it says `called when any data-bound property of a directive changes`. I don't use directives. Only this in my component.ts `this.questions = this.questionnaire.theQuestion[this.incremental];` so it's not gonna work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: in your `nextQuestion` you would need to reassign `this.questions` and `this.answers` to next set so that your component can re-render using new value.

Comment: @Rikin thanks, it works. And no need for `ngOnChanges`, I think it serves different purpose. You should post this as an answer, I will accept it. And any idea regarding the radio buttons having no text next to them? It works binding the value, I can see in the console, but in the browser there are just 3 radio buttons next to each other.

Comment: `{{answer}}` I think that's because your ngFor's scope is limited to your input. By moving up should do it. Try ng-container

Comment: @Rikin Yeah it worked right away. Just out of curiosity, have you already heard/read about this ngFor scope thing and knew that might be a problem or you just came up with this solution yourself by using common logic? Because I'm still pretty fresh to angular and I have no idea about things like ngFor scope and would never think about that. None of the beginners books even cover such a things. I should rather probably start reading docs start to finish instead.

Comment: Yeah that's kinda advanced topic I guess. I knew it from Angular 1 but if you look at the markup closely you can tell that ngFor is running on a HTML and in your case happens to be input which self closes so outside of it, internal scope value is not available from which you are trying to get `answer`. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: So in your case `{{answer}}` rendered to `{{undefined}}` thus it got ignored. Think of it as accessing `let i` value from `for loop` outside of javascript for-loop and you get ReferenceError

Comment: Yeah, now I get it. Actually I noticed that `<input>` was self closing and `{{answer}}` interpolation was being called outside the input, but it didn't get to me that this might actually be a problem. Well, now I will know. Danke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue was you never incremented to next set of question/answers from your service.
In your `nextQuestion` you would need to reassign `this.questions` and `this.answers` to next set so that your component can re-render using new value.

Answer (score 1):

Try a getter. The getter will execute each time Angular's change detection kicks in and regets the data for the page.

```
export class QuostionnaireComponent implements OnInit {

  get questions(): any{
    return this.questionnaire.theQuestion[this.incremental];
  }

  get answers(): any{
    return this.questionnaire.theChoices[this.incremental];
  }      
  correstAnswers:any;
  incremental: number = 0;
  constructor(private questionnaire: QuestionnaireService) { }
   nextQuestion():void {
     this.incremental++;
   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```